# using VIM distributed with OSX

Tags: macos, vim

I tried to install VIM with homebrew doing "brew install vim" and it told me that there was no formula for VIM however the terminal told me

```
Apple distributes vim with OS X, you can find it in /usr/bin.
```

However, I can't figure out how to get this install working. Can anyone explain?

Comment: What is confusing about it?  `vim filename` from a terminal, just as on Linux or etc..

Comment: I'm sort of new to programming...

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

- Homebrew's answer is quite elegant and straightforward, IMO.

  There is no homebrew formula for "Vim" but there is [one](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/macvim.rb) for "MacVim" so you have to do `$ brew install macvim` instead.
- Vim is already available on your Mac, in Terminal.app just type `$ vim filename` and hit `<enter>`. This version is a bit outdated and built with a limited feature set but, since you are new to Vim and programming, it's more than enough to get started.

  Do `$ vimtutor` a couple of times to learn the basics before doing anything else with Vim.
- Since you are new to programming, I'd suggest you do things progressively. Instead of using a package manager and the CLI right from the start why don't you simply [download MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) and work your way up from there?